How do we understand intuitively how the quotient topology changes as we make the relation bigger or smaller?
Provided a relation on the set of a topological space, we can turn that relation into an generated equivalence relation, and hence induce a quotient topology on the quotient set.
The open sets of the quotient topology are exactly those subsets of the quotient, for which their pre-image under the projection map (which takes each element in the initial set to their equivalence class representative) is open.
With that all in mind, if we have two relation $R_1 \subset R_2$ on a topological space $(A,\tau_A)$, what can we say about $(A_{R_1},\tau_{R_1})$ relates to $(A_{R_2}, \tau_{R_2})$ where the lower index represents the quotient set and quotient topology by the relation in the index, what can we say about either one in comparison with the other?
Could we, for example say that $\tau_{R_1}$ has more open sets than $\tau_{R_2}$ or vice a versa?

Reference for generated equivalence relation

So your intention is that $R_1$ and $R_2$ can be any relations on the set $A$ such that $R_1 \subset R_2$? And then you are asking a question about the two quotient spaces of $(A,\tau_A)$ with respect to the equivalence relation generated by $R_1$ and the with respect to the equivalence relation generated by $R_2$?

Yes... Is there any another interpretation of the question @Lee Mosher

I'm not suggesting any other interpretation. It's just that in my experience it is unusual to ponder quotient spaces starting with relations that are not already known to be equivalence relations. So I wanted to ask in order to be sure that I understood your intentions.

I think it's pretty intuitive to do this way. For example, we say that a cylinder is a rectangle with two sides glued together. when we may try formalize gluing we say which points go to which, however we need some more Elements in our relation ( eg reflexivity) to actually do the quotient topology construction. Relation more directly captures the idea of gluing than equivalence relation. Nonetheless only equivalence relation can be used to construct quotient topology hence we work with that @LeeMosher

Another question: you write $(A_{R_1},\tau_{R_2})$. This does not make sense to me. I would have expected  instead $(A_{R_2},\tau_{R_2})$. In other words, $\tau_{R_2}$ should be the quotient topology on the quotient set $A_{R_2}$, not on $A_{R_1}$.

That was a typo @LeeMosher

It does not really make sense to ask whether $\tau_{R_1}$ has "more open sets" than $\tau_{R_2}$, because they are topologies on different sets: $\tau_{R_1}$ is a topology on the set $A_1$; whereas $\tau_{R_2}$ is a topology on the set $A_2$.
But what you can do is to compare the quotient space $A_1$ and the quotient space $A_2$ using a natural function $A_1 \mapsto A_2$, and when you do that you see that this function is itself a quotient map.
For any set $A$ and any nested pair of relations $R_1 \subset R_2$ on $A$, let's consider the equivalence relations $Q_1,Q_2$ on $A$ that are generated by $R_1,R_2$. It's a pretty simple set theory exercise to prove that $Q_1 \subset Q_2$.
Let me simplify the notation by using $\tau_i$ to denote the quotient topology of $(A,\tau)$ on $A_i$, and let me denote $p_i : A \to A_i$ to denote the quotient map ($i=1,2$).
Using the fact that $Q_1 \subset Q_2$, it is another pretty simple set theory exercise to prove that there is a unique induced function $f : A_1 \to A_2$ such that $p_2 = f \circ p_1 : A \to A_1$. Namely, any $a_1 \in A_1$ is an equivalence class of $Q_1$, and there exists a unique $a_2 \in A_2$, i.e. a unique equivalence class of $Q_2$, such that $a_1 \subset a_2$; so in this situation we have $f(a_1)=a_2$.
So, the key exercise in this situation is that $f$ is itself a quotient  map from the topological space $(A_1,\tau_1)$ to the topological space $(A_2,\tau_2)$. (This is proved, for example, in Munkres "Topology" in his chapter on quotient spaces).
This does tell you something about the two quotient topologies in relation to the function $f$. As with any quotient map, the map $f$ gives you a bijection between two sets: the subset of $\tau_1$ consisting of its elements that are saturated with respect to $f$; and the full set $\tau_2$. So I suppose that in this sense you could say that there are "at least as many" elements of $\tau_1$ than there are of $\tau_2$.

Edit: I forgot to mention that for the following analysis to be fully accurate, we need to assume our initial space we study the quotients of is $T_0$, as otherwise we would technically lose information on how the topologically indistinguishable points are glued together. In a similar veign, the type of analysis I do here can only account for the $T_0$ quotient spaces. This, overall, is not a big loss, as non-$T_0$ quotients can be turned into $T_0$ quotients in a natural way.
The intuition for quotient spaces is that it is the space that arises when you glue certain points of the original space together. Naturally, if you glue more points together, the resulting space will be "smaller" is a sense.
To see how, consider a variant of the quotient space where the topology is still just the quotient topology, but we don't actually "glue together" the equivalence classes of our relation, but just leave the original underlying set alone (thus, the points glued together by the relation just become separate, but topologically indistinguishable points). If we call the resulting topology on $(X,\mathcal{T})$ just $\mathcal{T}_R$, where $R$ is a relation, we have the obvious relationship that $\mathcal{T}_{R_1}$ is (not nessesarily strictly) finer than $\mathcal{T}_{R_2}$ if (but not nessesarily only if) $R_1 \subseteq R_2$.
Whenever one sees an order-reversing correspondance like this, one has to wonder if it signifies a Galois Connection, and in this case we can actually show it does. If you do not know what a Galois connections is, here is a helpful wikipedia page on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection). You need not know all the nitty gritty details, but the definition at least is useful to know for this next part.
So: For any topology $\mathcal{T}'$ (not nessesarily strictly) coarser than $\mathcal{T}$, we can define the relation $R_{\mathcal{T}'}$ which makes topologically indistinguishable points equivalent. And conversely, for any relation $R$, we can just use the topology $\mathcal{T}_R$. I can show that these are Galois Adjoints: That is, $\mathcal{T}_{R'}$ is finer than $\mathcal{T'}$ if and only if $R' \subseteq R_{\mathcal{T}'}$ (assuming $\mathcal{T}'$ is coarser than $\mathcal{T}$).
This is true basically from the definition: if every element of $\mathcal{T}'$ is also an element of $\mathcal{T}_{R'}$, that means points that are topologically indistinguishable in $\mathcal{T}_{R'}$ are also indistinuishable in $\mathcal{T}'$, so $R' \subseteq R_{\mathcal{T}'}$. For the converse, if $R' \subset R_{\mathcal{T}'}$, then $\mathcal{T}_{R'}$ is by definition the finest topology (in $\mathcal{T}$) in which $aR'b$ implies $a$ and $b$ are topologically indistinguishable, so it will certainly be finer than $\mathcal{T}'$.
Like all Galois connections, this gives us a one to one correspondace, this time between quotient spaces of $(X,\mathcal{T})$ (denoted by the topologies on $X$ as described above), and relations of the form $R_{\mathcal{T}'}$. These type of relations can explicitly be characterised by the simple description of "equivalence relations, where equivalence classes can be distinguished by open neighbourhoods (i.e., one equivalence class has a neighbourhood the other does not)".
Hope that was a satisfactory (and followable) answer.

Denote the respective quotient maps by $q_1: A \to A_{R_1}$ and $q_2: A \to A_{R_2}$.
To be technical, you are considering two quotient spaces with different underlying sets, but topologies are only comparable when the underlying set is the same. However, because the equivalence relations satisfy $R_1 \subseteq R_2$, then it is true that the preimage of each element of $A_{R_1}$ under $q_1$ is entirely contained inside the preimage of some element of $A_{R_2}$ under $q_2$, and there is still something that can be said. I claim that
$$\mathcal{U} = q_1 (q_2^{-1} (\mathcal{V}))$$
is open in $(A_{R_1}, \tau_{R_1})$ for each $\mathcal{V}$ open in $(A_{R_2}, \tau_{R_2})$. It suffices to show that the set $B_\mathcal{V} = q_2^{-1} (\mathcal{V}) = \bigcup_{V \in \mathcal{V}} q_2^{-1} (V)$ is saturated with respect to $q_1$ (that is, $B_\mathcal{V} = q_1^{-1} (q_1 (B_\mathcal{V}))$) and that $B_\mathcal{V}$ is open in $(A, \tau_A)$.
($B_\mathcal{V}$ is saturated with respect to $q_1$) Let $a \in q_1^{-1} (q_1 (B_\mathcal{V}))$. Then
$$q_1 (a) \in q_1 (B_\mathcal{V}) = \bigcup_{V \in \mathcal{V}} q_1 (q_2^{-1} (V))$$
which shows that $q_1 (a) \in q_1 (q_2^{-1} (V_a))$ for some $V_a \in \mathcal{V}$. By definition, $a \times b \in R_1$ for some $b \in q_2^{-1} (V_a)$. But $R_1 \subseteq R_2$, so that $a \times b \in R_2$. Therefore,
$$q_2 (a) = q_2 (b) \in V_a \implies a \in q_2^{-1} (V_a) \implies a \in B_\mathcal{V}$$
as desired.
($B_\mathcal{V}$ is open in $(A, \tau_A)$) This follows directly from the fact that $\mathcal{V}$ is open in $(A_{R_2}, \tau_{R_2})$ and $q_2$ is continuous.
